# Facebook: difference between "Business or brand" and "Community or public figure" page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

When you click on **Create Page** on Facebook, you get to choose from the following options:

[image]

I have read several articles ([first](https://www.socialmediaexaminer.com/facebook-community-pages-what-your-business-needs-to-know/), [second](https://www.socialmediaexaminer.com/facebook-public-figure-page-how-to-create/), ...) on the topic about what these types pages are designed for... but I would like to know what exactly are the *technical* differences of both pages. Can they be converted from one to another later on?

The community type of page, does it work like in a group, where anyone can post to the main page feed?

What are the other technical differences?

I want to create a page to share essential oil recipes with people, where only I and my colleague will post. We want to provide people the value of the recipes, but we want to be the only ones who post there (not like a group), and organize events now and then, and sell products. But also provide the value of recipes for free. So I am asking to find out if I want "business or brand" or a "community" type of page.

Comment: The only thing I've been able to found is [this](https://www.facebook.com/help/918592541485077?helpref=uf_permalink). And also, community page doesn't contain "appointments" in the menu. But cannot find more differences here. If these are the only ones it would mean that business page is always better as it is more capable.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your Page's category, different features are available for your Page. The table below outlines the different Page categories (across) and the features that are available to them (down):
try this
https://www.facebook.com/help/918592541485077